# javascript regex group why do I get leading blanks?

Tags: javascript, regex

When matching "product product name cat1" with this regex I get " product name" with a leading blank, of course I could trim in javascript but is there a way to modify regex to not catch that blank ?

```
(product)((\s+)(.(?!cat1|cat2))+)
```

Comment: can we see test case?

Comment: Your example catches... just anything. https://regex101.com/r/yqOBvA/1

Comment: It could be somethink along `\bproduct\s+(.*?)\s+cat[12]\b` https://regex101.com/r/jmFzXd/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(product)(\s+)((?:(?!cat1|cat2).)+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bf8DhR/1).

Note:

- The tempered greedy token is fixed, see [Tempered Greedy Token - What is different about placing the dot before the negative lookahead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30900794/3832970)
- The capturing group 2 left boundary is moved after `(\s+)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at it is to use a non greedy quantifier `(.*?)` in a single capture group, and match either cat1 or cat2 if you are only interested in `product name`

```
\bproduct\s+(.*?)\s+cat[12]\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jmFzXd/1)